# Find all possible sums in 2D array - C++

Tags: arrays, sum, c++14

I have a 2D array like this

```
1 2
3 4
```

and I need to get all possible sums from it, in the above example the result will be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

any idea?

Comment: @Peter I'v tried alot of things and no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most algorithmic problems, there are many ways to do this. Depending on why you are doing this you are best to do this one on your own to get the most benefit out of this. In case you still can't figure it out, here is my own personal thought process.

First to make things cleaner to code realize that a 2D array in c++ is just syntactic sugar, and you can really access everything as if it were a 1D array.

For instance:

```
    int x[2][2];
    x[0][0] = 1;
    x[0][1] = 2;
    x[1][0] = 3;
    x[1][1] = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

       std::cout << x[0][i] << " ";
    }
```

will print out "1 2 3 4". You can also play with the dereference operator and discover there are many ways to access the elements that the brackets abstract away for you.

Now that you are able to access everything linearly, think about your algorithm. It looks like this is very similar to finding every subset of a set, for example all the subsets of the set {1,2,3,4} are: {}, {1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,3}, {1,3,4}, {1,4} {2}, {2,3}, {2,3,4}, {2,4}, {3}, {3,4}, {4}, {1,2,3,4}. Then to solve your problem just add the numbers in each subset up (excluding the empty set) and we get {1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8, 5, 2, 5, 9, 6, 3, 7, 4, 10}.

I see a problem, some numbers are repeated, for example {2,3} and {1,4} both add to be 5. How can we get rid of these? Again there are many ways, one simple way is to use a data structure that doesn't allow duplicates, for instances a hashet (or unordered_set in c++11 terms). If you need the sums ordered from lowest to highest as displayed in your original question, use a treeset (or a c++ set) instead of a hashset.

How do we find all the subsets of each set? There are many ways to do this, and many tutorials available online if you can't think of a solution.

Next think about the time and space complexity of the algorithm and some good test cases. Think about how this would scale if the input 2D array was so large that it couldn't fit on a single machine, how it would scale to process millions of different 2D arrays input, and what if millions of clients needed to use this algorithm all over the world.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you mean I can represent my 2D array as 1D array and get all possible subarrays and then add them to set data structure, that is true?

Comment: @whitedemon I don't think a subarray is the correct terminology. Subarray implies the numbers should be next to each other, here you really want the subsets (for this particular solution). But, yea... pretty much!

Comment: Exactly, thanks I will try this now, another question please, the maximum 2D array I work with it 300*300 can this algorithm run quickly?

Comment: Try analyzing it. Finding every subset is O(2^N), so a 300x300 array will produce O(2^300*300) stack calls. I don't think that would work...Like I said this was one very simple solution to get your mind going. Now that you have an idea try to optimize it.